# Why is query returning 10-digit ID?

Tags: apex, query, debugging

This is returned as the last row, the group record ID looks cut off

```
Group_Member__c:{Id=a181K000005jd11QAA, Contact__c=0031K00002tTqaQQAS, Group__c=a171K00000
```

Query is

```
            list<group_member__c> gmm = ([SELECT id, contact__r.mobilePhoneString__c, group__c from group_member__c where (is_sms_group__c = true and status__c = 'Active')]);
        system.debug(gmm);
```

Maybe the ID is correct and the discrepancy is at system.debug?

Edit - just realized the query isn't returning all of the records I need. Double-checked data by creating an equivalent report. Very weird

Answer (score 2):

Two things are going on here. First of all, you debug the list itself, so you get type coercion. If you want to view all elements in list with 10+, you should first serialize it.

Second, a while back Salesforce [made a change in Sprint 19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_developer_console.htm):

> To help prevent connection pool timeouts caused by exceptionally large queries, strings are now truncated at 512 characters in the Developer Console’s Log Inspector. This truncation applies to all string values in the Execution Log panel and to SOQL queries in the Source panel. You can view the complete string in a raw log file.

You have to **`View Raw Log`**.

Comment: Super helpful thanks!